# How to disable cut/copy option for all cells in Excel using C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

/*****
**--EDIT--**
**SOLUTION**
It is really weird how it finally worked out. The Interop Assembly I was using contained the methods to disable selection of the cells (`App.EnableSelection`). But it was not working. I installed MSOffice 2010 (was originally using 2007). Now, with the new version of assembly installed, and with no change in code at all, the excel sheet is behaving as expected, both, on Excel2007 and Excel2010. I'm still not able to comprehend what happened at the assembly level, but it finally solved my problem. :)
*****/

I'm writing a WPF application which programatically generates an excel file(which is a salary report). 
I've protected the file using the following code

```
myWorkSheet.Protect(Password);
```

The protection works fine but, I don't want the user to be able to copy any cell data to another sheet.
I've tried using the following code but it doesn't work

```
myWorkSheet.Application.CutCopyMode = (Excel.XlCutCopyMode)0;
```

I'm still able to copy cell data. What is going wrong?

NOTE: The environment is .NET Framework 4.5, MSOffice 2007, Microsoft.Office.Interop Assembly Version 1.6.0.0

What is really weird is that `Application.CutCopyMode` has types `False`,`xlCut`, and `xlCopy` [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.cutcopymode.aspx

The Version of Assembly I'm using does not contain the type `False`. Should I upgrade to Office 2010?

The COM reference I'm using is Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library Version 1.6.

I've been suggested to lock the cells and disable the selection on them, to prevent the user from copying cell data. Here is the code, but it doesn't work. Don't know why.

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//Adding some data to the sheet, modifying cells alignments,adding      border,headers

xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Locked = true;
xlWorkSheet.Protect("Lomesh", misValue, true, misValue, true, misValue,
misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
misValue, misValue, misValue);

xlWorkSheet.EnableSelection = Excel.XlEnableSelection.xlUnlockedCells;
```

The above code does not work. I'm still able to copy cell data.

```
//Saving using save dialog

xlWorkBook.SaveCopyAs(path);

xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);



xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `CutCopyMode` to False? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839532.aspx

Comment: If you're trying to prevent copying of information that won't be enough - users can still do screenshots, reference the data in formulas, or even re-type the numbers.  Not saying you _shouldn't_ do it, but don't expect it to be foolproof.

Comment: The type `False` does not seem to be available with the the version of Excel I'm using(Office2007). That the problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to prevent copying of information. I fully agree that users can do screenshots and all the rest, but the requirements are limited to preventing the user from doing a copy operation on the cells. I know it's not foolproof :)

Comment: Might be an hack, but can't you just handle the SelectionChange event on the sheet ? Something like `OnSelectionChanged(...) Range("A1").Select`.
Embed the workbook in your app and use it as a basis for generated ones.

Comment: @xum59 The `selectionChanged` event does not seem to work. I can still copy the cell data. Can you please elaborate your solution? Maybe I'm doing it wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Protecting the sheet is not enough. You also have to:

(1) Lock the cells, if they are not already locked, and

(2) Set the protection to not enable selection of locked cells:

```
myWorkSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
```

This will prevent the user from selecting the locked cells, which then prevents them from being able to copy them.

Comment: The solution you suggested didn't work,Sir. I'm still able to select the cells, contrary to what is expected after adding the code you suggested.I've added my code to the question description. You could have a look at it.